# Laravel Eloquent: Nested relationship and save data

Tags: laravel

I have three models.

```
PERSON (hasOne(EMPLOYEE), hasMany(CHILDREN))
id,
name

EMPLOYEE
id,
person_id

CHILDREN
id,
person_id
```

I want to add a child to person model but i have access to EMPLOYEE_ID. I tried to code but it doesn't work.

```
$employee->person()->children()->save($child);
```

and

```
$employee->person()->children()->associate($child);
```

But both doesn't work. I don't know if this can be accomplished by just one line of code.

Comment: What are your models? Can you paste your relationships?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way, When you are calling `person()` it will return the relation instead of the object itself.

```
$employee->person->children()->save($child);
```

Comment: should this be `associate()` instead of `save()`?

Comment: You have mentioned that the relationship is `hasMany`as it should be, so it should be `save`. If it is a `belongsTo` relation then you can use `associate`.